# How can I use a different partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have a ubuntu system with a disk with different partitions (some I cannot use)

in the end I have a 127 GB partition almost full (just 12GB free) that is /dev/sda5 and is mounted at the file system root.

I have managed to get me an adjacent unallocated space of 54GB (Device /dev/sda) .

I was thinking of expanding my root partition but that is not possible (since I am booting on it and for some reason I am unable to boot from USB- a complete different problem)

So I am thinking why not making the free space into a different partition. Then I will have 54GB on a new partition.

My question is (I am unexperienced with ubuntu) if I do this, how can I use this partition with my system and avoid all the "not enough space " errors.

Can I mount the partition somewhere over the `/home` or even better `/home/myuser' so as to have more space available?

Comment: Advice: Solve your unable-to-boot-from-USB problem first. Workarounds cause more trouble later.

Comment: You can use command or GUI tool (you provided no OS/release details to really be specific) to create the partition, then edit your *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab`) to control where it mounts to (or a number of other options but I'd use *fstab*)  If it mounts over an existing directory, it'll *hide* or *shadow* the original contents of that directory, so prepare it before hand (ie. copy files to it that will be shadowed). What you put there, and where you put it is up to you.

Comment: @guiverc so if I create a new directory over `/home` and I mount the partition there will my disk space in `/home` be increased?

Comment: If you mount the 54GB partition on /home, you'll have 54GB available to home, and whatever files you copied onto that partition are all that will be there  Any prior contents in your previously used /home directory will be shadowed by the new mount.

Comment: @guiverc I mean mount it over say `/home/myuser/mynewdisk/` , meaning a subdirectory in `/home`. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can control where it mounts, and whatever directory you `mount` it to will appear in your `df` (*disk free*) and like commands, and it'll have it's own 54gb available to it (that won't impact other mounts).

Comment: My problem now is that I don't have rights over it. If I want to copy or paste anything I have to sudo it. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can change ownership with the chown command. I suggest you google it for examples and work out what you need in your case. It’s not as hard as it might look. Try it out on a temporary directory on your system somewhere first. Give the ownership to root then take it back. You will need to make it recursive. All that means is apply the change to sub directories and files

Answer (score 0):

After creating the partition (say under `/dev/sda4`) you can type `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt` and you will be able to mount the partition inside `/mnt`. Then you can cd into `/mnt` and access the partition.

You can also create your own mount point. For example `sudo mkdir /mnt/sda4` and then run `sudo mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/sda4` to mount.

Comment: I did this but I have a problem. I don't have access to it (to copy and paste for ex) and I have to use the terminal and sudo my way to it. right now I am `sudo cp` a file and I don't know if it will be finished alright. Is there a way that I have access to this mounted region?

Comment: You should change the permissions. For example if the username you are using is `kansai` and you have mounted the partition in `/mnt/sda4`, then execute `sudo chmod -R ugo+rxw /mnt/sda4` to get permissions for everyone to read write and execute inside all folders and subfolders of `/mnt/sda4`

Comment: If also you would like to change ownership type `sudo chown kansai:kansai /mnt/sda4`. But I thing the permission change will allow you to copy freely. In order to see if your copy command works try opening a new terminal and run `ls /mnt/sda4` and check if the filesizes change inside.